# How to bind XAttribute Value by Foreach

Tags: xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

```
var xEle = new XElement("ContentDetails",
            from emp in _lstContents
            select new XElement("Contents",
                        new XAttribute("key", emp.Key),
                        new XAttribute("PublishedDate", emp.PublishedDate),
                        new XAttribute("FilePathURL", emp.FilePathURL),
                        new XAttribute("ID", emp.TitleID),
                        new XAttribute("ContentName", emp.Name)
                        ));
```

_lstContents which contains whole records. i need to frame XmlDocument by LinQ operation
i know it could achievable and i done it.
This is my sample XML what i've done so:

```
<ContentDetails>
  <Contents ContentName="Sample Project Plan SOW" ID="3"
        FilePathURL="http://192.168.30.59/contentraven/Uploads/Custom_View_LLC/EncryptedFile/zsg34g45tfblrkvzjh0cdlvs_17_7_2012_19_24_3.doc"
        PublishedDate="2012-07-10T14:37:02.073" key="310-072012-A5CDE"/>
</ContentDetails>
```

but now what i need is

```
<ContentDetails>
  <Contents ContentName="Sample Project Plan SOW" ID="3"
        FilePathURL="http://192.168.30.59/contentraven/Uploads/Custom_View_LLC/EncryptedFile/zsg34g45tfblrkvzjh0cdlvs_17_7_2012_19_24_3.doc"
        PublishedDate="2012-07-10T14:37:02.073" key="310-072012-A5CDE"/>
   <categories>
      <category id="1" categoryname="Category-1" contentid="3"/>
      <category id="2" categoryname="Category-2" contentid="3"/>
      <category id="3" categoryname="Category-3" contentid="3"/>
  </categories>
</ContentDetails>
```

i'm trying something like this

```
var xEle = new XElement("ContentDetails",
            from emp in _lstContents
            select new XElement("Contents",
                        new XAttribute("key", emp.Key),
                        new XAttribute("PublishedDate", emp.PublishedDate),
                        new XAttribute("FilePathURL", emp.FilePathURL),
                        new XAttribute("ID", emp.TitleID),
                        new XAttribute("ContentName", emp.Name),
                            new XElement("Categories",
                                new XElement("Category",
                                    new XAttribute("ID", emp.Category.ForEach(_P => _P.CategoryID ),
                                    new XAttribute("CategoryName", emp.Category.ForEach(_P => _P.CategoryName))
                                )

                        ));
```

how could i achieve this?

emp.Category is a Property List in _lstContents List;

i need to create number of CategoryName attribute as much found in emp.Category.

please refer the screenshot as enclosed.
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to project the items in your category collection to `category` elements.  It's not much different to how you projected items in `_lstContents` to `Contents` elements.

```
var contentDetails =
    new XElement("ContentDetails",
        from contents in _lstContents
        select new XElement("Contents",
            new XAttribute("ContentName", contents.Name),
            new XAttribute("ID", contents.TitleID),
            new XAttribute("FilePathURL", contents.FilePathURL),
            new XAttribute("PublishedDate", contents.PublishedDate),
            new XAttribute("key", contents.Key),
            new XElement("categories",
                from category in contents.Category
                select new XElement("category",
                    new XAttribute("id", category.CategoryID),
                    new XAttribute("categoryname", category.CategoryName),
                    new XAttribute("contentid", category.ContentID)
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: i'm getting "Value cannot be null" @ contents.Category for some contents! how do i chk is not null?